# Can floor tiles be installed on walls?

Tags: bathroom, walls, flooring, floor

I am building a home and would like to install floor tiles on wall also, please let me know if it possible to install floor tiles on walls?

Comment: What kind of floor tiles?

Comment: The floor kind. ;)

Comment: Yes.. Make sure you using a strong tile backing and not plasterboard!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to install floor tiles on walls.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use almost any tile on either wall or floor, the only things that differentiate the two would be

- Texture and surface smoothness - rough tiles are made for floors to be anti slip when wet
- Design and pattern - the design is often more suited to floors or walls
- material thickness and strength - the stronger (hence thinner) materials are more compatible for walls since they will be lighter and less likely to fall off.  (ie porcelain or ceramic)

The important thing is that you use a wall adhesive for walls and floor cement for floors, since the wall cement will have more adhesion strength to hold up the tile.

Answer (score 0):

As the The Evil Greebo said it is possible one of the factors to consider is the weight of floor tiles on wall as they are generally thicker/heavier. Hence they can be more difficult to lay on the wall.

Comment: I thought the depth of my answer should reflect the depth of the question. ;)